# Sqlplus - creating new users

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus

I have downloaded Oracle - OraDb11g_home1 and I want to use sqlplus.
The problem is, when I open sqlplus, it's prompts me for username and password which I don't think I have.
Is there a way to log in as a default super user and create a new account?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start SQL*Plus:

```
C:\> sqlplus /NOLOG
```

Connect as SYSDBA:

```
SQL> CONNECT / AS SYSDBA
```

change password and connect again.

```
ALTER USER username ACCOUNT UNLOCK;

ALTER USER username IDENTIFIED BY password;
```